# Maven Get Specific Classes

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Is there a way that I can get maven to only include specific .class files when importing dependencies into uber jar (shade).  I'm looking for a way to get files that contain "Client" in their name to be pulled out of the dependency jars and added to the final jar.  Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency%3aunpack_mojo) like this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId><!--dependency groupId--></groupId>
                                <artifactId><!--dependency artifactId--></artifactId>
                                <version><!--depedency version--></version>
                                <includes>**/*Client*.java</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), you can a [filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#filters), which will allow you to filter which artifacts get shaded, but as well as which classes to exclude or include.

Here's the example they provide:

```xml
<filters>
  <filter>
    <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
    <includes>
      <include>org/junit/**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </filter>
</filters>
```